# When is the "Exploration Bonus" awarded in Escape from Tarkov?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Occasionally, a "+100xp" notification designated "Exploration Bonus" pops up in the middle of the raid. The games provides no additional explanation.

- When exactly does this happen? On which maps?
- How often can it happen (repeatedly)?
- Can it be forced to happen through some action?
- Is it capped in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Exploration bonus is a moderate amount of bonus XP the player gets for exploring the map. You can only earn it the first time you pass through a place that would award the bonus. Subsequent raids do not give Exploration bonuses for re-treading the same ground.

Typically, but not always, it involves visiting side pathways and other areas that wouldn't qualify as the map's main thoroughfare. The trails on Customs or the tunnels on Factory are good examples. Certain rooms will award it too, like the office room in Factory or the decrepit train station on Woods.

If you have an idea of what parts of the map will award an exploration bonus then you can visit these spots and be awarded these experience points quickly, but because they can only be awarded once per wipe, there isn't a strong incentive to do it. Your character will be able to earn it through standard play, it isn't necessary to drastically change up your playstyle to achieve these bonuses.

Comment: It is a one time thing - but FWIW it is something that resets every wipe. And some of them are more than 100, I think the Factory ones can give up to 300xp

Comment: @chebureki The exploration bonuses are location based - time has no impact, they're still one location.

Comment: I have checked this time, the frozen-in-time locations `factory4_night` and `factory4_day` award the bonus separately, unlike the other locations that are treated as the same place regardless of time.